# Multiple condition IF statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I've got an if statement with multiple conditions that I just can't seem to get right

```
if(((ISSET($_SESSION['status'])) && ($_SESSION['username']=="qqqqq")) ||     
((ISSET($_SESSION['status'])) && ($_SESSION['company']=="wwwwww")) || 
((ISSET($_SESSION['status'])) && ($_SESSION['company']=="ffffffff")) || 
((ISSET($_SESSION['status'])) && ($_SESSION['company']=="ggggggg")) || 
((ISSET($_SESSION['status'])) && ($_SESSION['company']=="hhhhhhh")) || 
($_SESSION['LOGINTYPE']=="ADMIN")) {
```

Its supposed to return true if the status is set as well as either one of those company names OTHERWISE if the logintype is admin it should also return true regardless of company or status

Comment: wow! that is one LONG condition!

Comment: You want to look at the [`switch` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php). :)

Comment: @Pekka no, at [Decompose Conditional](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/decompose-conditional) or better yet [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism) and/or the [State Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state)

Comment: @JohnP: [I've seen longer](http://ayende.com/blog/archive/2010/08/31/it-really-happened-legacy-programmers-tales.aspx)

Comment: @pam What is "status" conceptually?

Comment: status of the session e.g. logged in

Comment: @pam than it should be named `isLoggedIn` or `isAuthenticated` and not `status` which is completely vague, especially since it's within the rather generic Session superglobal and not some object setting the context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this :

```
if (
  (isset($_SESSION['status']) && $_SESSION['username']=="qqqqq")
  || (isset($_SESSION['status']) && in_array($_SESSION['company'], array('wwwwww', 'ffffffff', 'ggggggg', 'hhhhhhh')))
  || $_SESSION['LOGINTYPE']=="ADMIN"
)
```

Rewriting the condition to try to make it a bit more easier to read might help :

- One possible case per line :

  - status set and username OK
  - status set and company OK
  - admin
- Using in_array instead of several tests on company -- I think it's easier to understand

Comment: I would advise to assign an array of possible companies to a variable (i.e,. `$validCompanies = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz')`) instead of creating it in `if` statement - it will make condition more readable.

Answer (score 2):

At the very minimum, rework it so it reads what you said it should do:

> Its supposed to return true if the status is set as well as either one of those company names OTHERWISE if the logintype is admin it should also return true regardless of company or status

```
function mayAccessResource(array $sessionState)
{
    return (hasStatus($sessionState) && isAllowedUserOrCompany($sessionState))
        || isAdmin($sessionState);
}
```

Then add methods for those encapsulating the single tests:

```
function hasStatus($sessionState)
{
    return isset($sessionState['status']);
}

function isAllowedUserOrCompany($sessionState)
{
    return isAllowedUser($sessionState) || isAllowedCompany($sessionState);
}

function isAllowedUser($sessionState)
{
    return isset($sessionState['user']) 
        && $sessionState['user'] === 'blah';
}

function isAllowedCompany($sessionState)
{
    $allowedCompanies = array('foo', 'baz', 'baz');
    return isset($sessionState['company']) 
        && in_array($sessionState['company'], $allowedCompanies);
}

function isAdmin($sessionState)
{
    return isset($sessionState['LOGINTYPE'])
        && $sessionState['LOGINTYPE'] === 'admin';
}
```

That's still far from perfect because it hardcodes way too much information, but at least it is much more readable now. Since all of these operate on the session State, it would be much prettier there was an object SessionState. Even better would be to tease the various possible session states further apart and have a Company, User and AccessControl class.

Also note the comments below your question.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks for fleshing out your comments, I was about to ask you for examples

Comment: @Pekka the above is only a rough example for [Decompose Conditional](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/decompose-conditional) though. It doesnt show how to make it use Polymorphism, nor does it show the use of a State Pattern. Would be too much to add. After I wrote [half a "book" about OOP here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329664/is-this-correct-object-oriented-programing-in-php/5333415#5333415), I cannot be bothered to write yet another one, so the above must suffice :)

Comment: nice. Have you ever considered starting a blog? Quality PHP blogs are few and far between.

Comment: @Pekka [I do have a blog](http://gooh.posterous.com) though there isn't that much content on it.

Answer (score 1):

Some formatting would make that a lot easier to parse mentally =)  Plus you probably could simplify the companies aspect of things by creating an array of permitted companies.  Testing one at a time makes this if() difficult to maintain and read - each time you add a company you risk breaking the logic.

Also, it looks like if `$_SESSION['LOGINTYPE'] == 'ADMIN'`, this is an override which should always be true, while otherwise you always need $_SESSION['status'] to be set.

```
$companies = array(
    'wwww'=>true,
    'ffff'=>true,
    'gggg'=>true,
    'hhhh'=>true
);
if (
    $_SESSION['LOGINTYPE'] == 'ADMIN'
||  isset($_SESSION['status'])
    && (
        $_SESSION['username'] == 'qqqqq'
    ||  isset($companies[$_SESSION['company']])
    )
) {
    ...
}
```

Or maybe more clearly:

```
$pass = false;
if ($_SESSION['LOGINTYPE'] == 'ADMIN') {
    $pass = true;
} else if (isset($_SESSION['status'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'qqqq') $pass = true;
    if (isset($companies, $_SESSION['company']) $pass = true;
}
if ($pass) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually (correctly) rewriting the expression in the original post in a way that makes sense. I also hadn't realized that isset() could take multiple parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
if (!$_SESSION['LOGINTYPE']=="ADMIN") {
    return false;
}

if (!ISSET($_SESSION['status']) {
    return false
}

if ($_SESSION['username']=="qqqqq") {
    return true;
}

// etc
```

Or use switch starting from the the third conditional.

Even better would be to make this object oriented:

```
if ($this->user->isAdmin()) || $this->user->belongsToCompany($this->allowedCompanies)
```

This reads even better through the creation of a 'higher level language'.

Note: it's not about getting the least character on the as few lines as possible.

Comment: +1 for making a case for code which is actually readable, which IMO is the point of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use try-catch-blocks and set a variable to true if a case becomes true?

It's much clearer to read and sustain.

```
try($foo) {
    catch x:
    $bar = true;

    default:
    $bar = false;
}
```