# How to write long IF more prettier?

Tags: php

I have long IF:

```
if(rand(1, 100) == 22 && $smth < time() && 
$smths > 5 && $sxsxsx > 250 && 
!$_SESSION['false'])
{
    echo "wow, big if just happened!";
}
```

How to write it more "prettier"?

Comment: As a sidenote, it may be best to put !$_SESSION['false'] as the first test. Remember that PHP will stop looking once it encountered a "stop" condition. So put the "easy" tests or tests that are likely to return False first ... Now you generate a random number AND get the time before checking a simple variable ...

Comment: //Unappropriate
if (false) { //do the code }
this is right in the 99% of cases :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In accordance with my answer to the related

- [Multiple condition IF statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338219/multiple-condition-if-statement/5338561#5338561)

this should be refactored with [Decompose Conditional](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/decompose-conditional), which means you should make the individual tests into separate functions. And you should get rid of the magic numbers and meaningless variable names. I would give you an example on how to do that for your code, but the code is incomprehensible.

Answer (score 17):

I prefer breaking before the boolean operators.

```
if(rand(1, 100) == 22
   && $smth < time()
   && $smths > 5
   && $sxsxsx > 250
   && !$_SESSION['false']
)
```

Comment: while the *formatting* is prettier indeed, it is still completely unreadable regarding it's intention and [should be refactored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419660/how-to-write-long-if-more-prettier/5419812#5419812).

Comment: I'd also put each condition in its own brackets. That visually seperates things, since right now it's just a soup of operators.

Answer (score 6):

I like to name my conditions and group them so its clear what their purpose is.

```
$is22 = rand(1, 100) == 22;
$someTime = $smth < time() && $smths > 5;
$meetsSx = $sxsxsx > 250;
$inSession = !$_SESSION['false'];
if ($is22 && $someTime && $meetsSx && $inSession) {
     // do something
}
```

Comment: This way costly expressions allways get computed, even if first condition is false.

Comment: True, but none of these are too costly.

Answer (score 5):

```
$isSomethingValid = rand(1, 100) == 22
   && $smth < time()
   && $smths > 5
   && $sxsxsx > 250
   && !$_SESSION['false'];

if ($isSometingValid) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Always indent to the enclosing statement one extra than the body of the block. You would write a function like this:

```
function (reallylongparam, reallylongparam, reallylongparam,
        reallylongparam, reallylongparam) {
    doStuff()
}
```

so you'd write your if statement like this:

```
if(rand(1, 100) == 22 && $smth < time() && $smths > 5
       && $sxsxsx > 250 && !$_SESSION['false']) {
    doStuff();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

probably

```
if(
    rand(1, 100) == 22 && 
    $smth < time() && 
    $smths > 5 && 
    $sxsxsx > 250 && 
    !$_SESSION['false']
) {
    echo "wow, big if just happened!";
}
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Making your code readable is a very important aspect when it comes to supporting your code - someone else might have to do that support.

Have a look at [coding styles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style) (search around for more info if you must).

Personally I would format that snippet like so:

```
if  (
    rand(1, 100) == 22
    &&
    $smth < time()
    && 
    $smths > 5
    &&
    $sxsxsx > 250
    && 
    !$_SESSION['false']
    )
{
    echo "wow, big if just happened!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just encapsulate the boolean logic in a seperate function

Answer (score 0):

You could also make your variable names easier to read.